# How to de-select radio and dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have group of radiogroup with name `managerelradio`. I am showing these on change event of dropdown event but issue is when I hide these values remain in radiogroup. Means when I show radiogroup next time selected radio remains selected. How can I deselct it. and same action I wish to perform for dropdown also.

```
  <label><input type="radio" name="managerelradio" value="Yes" id="Add">Add</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="managerelradio" value="No" id="Remove">Remove</label> 

 <select name="childsgrel" id="childsgrel" class="select">
 <option value="">--Relationship--</option>
 <option value="Father" <?php if ($relation=="Father") echo "selected";?>>Father</option>
 </select>
```

Means I want to again disselect both radio group as well as dropdown.

```
$('#childsgrel').change(function() {
        var relationship = $('#childsgrel').val();
        if(relationship == '' | relationship == null){
                $('.managechilddiv_2').hide('fast');
                $('input[name="managerelradio"]').attr('selected', false);

            }
        else if(relationship != '' ){
                $('.managechilddiv_2').show('fast');
        }
 });
```

// I want to disselect radio group on `$('#childsgrel').change(function() {`...

Comment: Use `checked="false"`. Not sure about the dropdowns... I think its `selected="false"`

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your current jQuery it's hard to say exactly where to put this, but to deselect a selected radio element:

```
$('input:radio[name="managerelradio"]:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wMPXR/1/).

References:

- [`:radio` selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector).
- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Yes it work for radios... How can I make dropdown menu as default.. And what is prop function?

Comment: As to your question about the prop function, the blueish texts in the answer are links. Put your mouse arrow above them until a hand appears and then press the left button. You'd be interested in the `prop()` one.

Comment: @BalusC I am left-handed so I need to press the right button, correct?  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Uncheck radios
$(":radio").prop("checked", false);

// Unselect drop-downs
$("select").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

[Live Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUFbP/)

Comment: Great but If I want particular value for select than? I mean my default I want again.